# showing parent/child records in asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, parent-child

Ok I can't seem to figure this one out..I have 1 table which has column id, parentid
this allows an option to have a sub-option.  So it would be something like this:

```
id  |  parentid
1   |    null
2   |    null
3   |      1
```

How I need it to show in my gridview is like this:

```
id  |  parentid
 1  |     null
 3  |      1
 2  |     null
```

any ideas I would be most greatful..and just in case I have searched and tried Sql COALESCE  on the select but that didn't work either..

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to answer your question in any meaningful way.  Your "how it should look" option only appears to center the data and swap positions of item's 2 and 3.  How exactly is that order being determined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a ListView or DataList instead of a GridView. This should put you on the right path:

```
<table width="595px">
    <asp:DataList BackColor="#ffffff" id="DataList1" DataKeyField="<ID>" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" runat="server" Width="100%">     
        <ItemTemplate>
           <tr>
              <td>
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="+" OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command" CommandArgument='<%#Container.ItemIndex%>'></asp:LinkButton>    
              </td>
              <td><%#Eval("<COLUMN NAME>")%></td>
              <td><%#Eval("<COLUMN NAME>")%></td>
              <td><%#Eval("<COLUMN NAME>")%></td>
           </tr>
           <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcChildView" runat="server">
               <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" Width="100%">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <tr>
                          <td><%#Eval("<CHILD OLUMN NAME>")%></td>
                          <td><%#Eval("<CHILD COLUMN NAME>")%></</td>
                          <td><%#Eval("<CHILD COLUMN NAME>")%></</td>                           
                       </tr>
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:DataList>
           </asp:Panel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</table>
```

And when the user clicks the LinkButton/Button in DataList1, do something like this:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    //pass index of item in command argument
    int itemIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);      

    //find the pnlChildView control
    PlaceHolder childViewHolder = (PlaceHolder)DataList1.Items[itemIndex].FindControl("plcChildView");
    if (childViewHolder != null)
    {
        //toggle visibility of childViewPanel and bind child list if panel is visible

        if (childViewHolder.Visible)
        {
            DataList childList = childViewHolder.FindControl("DataList2");
            if (childList != null)
            {
                int keyValue = (int)DataList1.DataKeys[itemIndex];

                //bind the list using DataList1 data key value
                childList.DataSource = <DATA SOURCE>; //get data using keyValue
                childList.DataBind();
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked for me but because they needed any sub-option to be handled on the fly we are going to go with a treeview :S  But just wanted to let you know this really worked for me.